# Not Able to Get Applications Url for Skype for Business

Tags: skype-for-business, ucwa, skypedeveloper

I'm trying to use the REST API in Skype for Business Online by following the instructions here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt590891(v=office.16).aspx.

I make the first call to the discovery service, and then get the discovery URL back for the user; it looks like this for me:
https://webdir0b.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user

I then make the call to Azure and successfully get an access token back for https://webdir0b.online.lync.com.  The next step is where things break down - I make a request again to the discovery Url for the user and include the access token.  The call returns successfully, but the problem is that it doesn't have the "applications" url in the payload as described in the documentation.  Instead it returns the same exact info as I got when I called the general discovery endpoint (https://webdir.online.lync.com/autodiscover/autodiscoverservice.svc/root).  I've triple checked that I'm calling the correct endpoint so...any hints as to why I'm not getting the expected payload when calling the discovery Url for the user?

Comment: Okay...what the hell. I kept poking at this and - one time - it actually returned the correct payload. Just by luck I noticed that it went to a different server, so...is this API not working on all SFB servers?  Specifically now if I hard-code the discovery endpoint to https://webdir1a.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user then I get the correct payload.  If I just take what the general discover endpoint gives me, then it fails every time, unless it happens to land on this server.  So what's the deal??

Comment: It would be interesting to see the request/response trail to see the larger picture as you shouldn't be routed back to location A if you already passed that point.  If you are unable to you might consider getting a Fiddler trace and reaching out to MSFT as there are likely to be some minor hitches in enabling every Online user and you might be one of the unlucky few.

Comment: I'll try and answer as short as possible - I got this working. 1st issue - when you don't get "applications" in the result, you should have a "redirect" value instead.  Keep following that and doing your GET against it (using the process of getting access tokens and adding the auth header) and eventually you should get the applications Url.  2nd issue - after you get your applications URL, you need to go get another access token and use the host name of the applications URL as the resource ID.  Then you can post and create your app.  Really hope this helps someone.  :-)

Comment: That would be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try and answer as short as possible - I got this working. 1st issue - when you don't get "applications" in the result, you should have a "redirect" value instead. Keep following that and doing your GET against it (using the process of getting access tokens and adding the auth header) and eventually you should get the applications Url. 2nd issue - after you get your applications URL, you need to go get another access token and use the host name of the applications URL as the resource ID. Then you can post and create your app. Really hope this helps someone. :-)

Answer (score 0):

(Am I really replying to Steve Pescka? :o)

In my case performing GET on the `user` resource
`GET https://webdir0e.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user?originalDomain=contoso.onmicrosoft.com`

returns the following

```
 <resource rel="user" href="https://webpoolam30e08.infra.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/rtc/2012/03/ucwa">  
   <link rel="applications" href="https://webpoolam30e08.infra.lync.com/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications" revision="2" />
   <link rel="xframe" href="https://webpoolam30e08.infra.lync.com/Autodiscover/XFrame/XFrame.html" />
 </resource>
```

So it contains the URI for `applications` resource, where to POST in order to create your application.
I have an O365 E5 license

Comment: Hey, thanks Massimo, it's really me.  :-)   I appreciate you posting what you have, but I'm still getting temporarily stuck because I'm not getting the same data back you are.  I'm still poking at it so I guess we'll see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. When the results of calling the user resource does not include applications, it will include a redirect value.  Here's an example:

A call here:

```
https://webdir0b.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user
```

May return the following:

```
{"_links":{"self":{"href":"https://webdir0b.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/user"},"xframe":{"href":"https://webdir2a.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/xframe"},"redirect":{"href":"https://webdir2a.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root"}}}
```

Which includes this redirect

```
"redirect":{"href":"https://webdir2a.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root"}}}
```

To continue, you'll then need to make an Azure AD auth call, passing ONLY the value of the protocol://servername as the resource.  This means reducing the following:

```
https://webdir2a.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root
```

To be just this:

```
https://webdir2a.online.lync.com/
```

Now that you have a valid token for webdir2a.online.lync.com, you'll then need to append "/oauth/user" to the re-direct URL.  You'll notice the initial call included this in the URL whereas the redirect URL doesn't.

Call the updated re-direct URL

```
https://webdir2a.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user
```

And you should get what you're after:

```
{"_links":{"self":{"href":"https://webpooldm12a04.infra.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user"},"applications":{"href":"https://webpooldm12a04.infra.lync.com/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications","revision":"2"},"xframe":{"href":"https://webpooldm12a04.infra.lync.com/Autodiscover/XFrame/XFrame.html"}}}
```

Which is the applications resource

```
"applications":{"href":"https://webpooldm12a04.infra.lync.com/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications","revision":"2"}
```

For the interested, I've created a [.NET-based console app](https://github.com/tamhinsf/ucwa-sfbo-console) that demonstrates how to sign in to Skype for Business Online via the UCWA API - and in doing so, handles the autodiscovery process, re-directs, application creation, amongst other things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use the REST API in Skype for Business Online by following the instructions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt590891(v=office.16).aspx.

I make the first call to the discovery service, and then get the discovery URL back for the user; it looks like this for me: https://webdir0b.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user

I then make the call to Azure and successfully get an access token back for https://webdir0b.online.lync.com. The next step is where things break down - I make a request again to the discovery Url for the user and include the access token.  I get **500 - Internal server error.There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.**

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Consider posting a new question if the answers here aren’t applicable to you.