# Skype for business using ucwa in uwp applications

Tags: skype-for-business

i am trying to use ucwa apis to get the users presence status. but I am getting issue as failed to get application resource

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423045/not-able-to-get-applications-url-for-skype-for-business/38107666) which discusses how to perform UCWA Autodiscovery for Skype for Business Online and get the application URL.

Presence has recently become available in preview for UCWA-powered SFB Online apps.

I've created a [C#-based example](https://github.com/tamhinsf/ucwa-sfbo-console) that you can use as a basis in your UWP app, which includes changing presence for a user.