# Display the user presence/status using Skype web SDK or UCWA in UWP app

Tags: uwp, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, ucwa

I am having a requirement on just want to show/display the Skype for business user presence(Busy, Available, Off Work etc) in UWP app.

I have gone through the following documentations,

[Skype Web SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/skypewebsdk)

I found that using Skype Web SDK we can show that but I am getting struck how can I use the Skype Web SDK in UWP app.

Can anyone know how can I use the Skype Web SDK in UWP app? or If have any other way to get skype user presence please help me out.

I also tried to use [UCWA 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/unifiedcommunicationswebapi2_0) , but got struck to get application uris

Answer (score 1):

I have found answer for my question after reading the following posts

[A Sample Console Application (C# based)](https://github.com/tamhinsf/ucwa-sfbo-console)

Understanding the flow and How to get Application URLs

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423045/not-able-to-get-applications-url-for-skype-for-business/38107666)

To get User Presence I added onemore method to the UcwaPresence like below: (You will find the UcwaPresence helper class in above mentioned sample app)

You have a GetPresenceURL method in UcwaPresence helper class with the help of that you can get the ucwaPresenceRootUri.

Once you get the GetPresence URL(here in my case called ucwaPresenceRootUri) then call the following method to get status

```
public static async Task<string> GetPresence(HttpClient httpClient, AuthenticationResult ucwaAuthenticationResult, String ucwaPresenceRootUri)
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", ucwaAuthenticationResult.AccessToken);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var httpResponseMessage =
            httpClient.GetAsync(ucwaPresenceRootUri).Result;
        var presenceJsonStr = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var presenceObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UcwaPresenceObject>(presenceJsonStr);
        Debug.WriteLine(presenceJsonStr);
        return presenceObj.availability;
    }
```

***Credits***

[tam-huynh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5874738/tam-huynh)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Javascript imlementation for building UWP apps, you can make use of Skype Web SDK. You just need to include the Skype Web SDK in your app and then you can directly use the methods from your app. You can refer this 
http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2016/03/skype-web-sdk-online-setting-everything-up-step-by-step-guide/

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information Shahzad, Is there a way that I can Subscribe events for user presence change. I mean I want to notify my client app when user changes his/her status. Is it possible?

Comment: @narendramacha Yes there is definitely. When you access a Person object, you can subscribe to changes using person object. Something like `person.status.changed(function (newStatus) {
                        // handle status change
                    });`  You can also refer to these links [Skype Web SDK Samples](https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk)

Comment: is it possible to do the same using rest ucwa apis? Because I used ucwa , if yes can you share how to subscribe using rest apis?

Comment: "Error 403 - This web app is stopped."  - webpage you link does not work. Can you please use http://paste.ubuntu.com/ or http://gist.github.com/ to paste contents to have them permanently please?